# Conditional where clause in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, bind-variables

I have database table as below

```
+----------+----------+------------+
| emp_code | emp_name | emp_status | 
+----------+----------+------------+
|   01     |   aaa    |     A      |
|   02     |   bbb    |     A      |
|   03     |   ccc    |     A      |
|   04     |   ddd    |     I      |
|   05     |   eee    |     I      |
|   06     |   fff    |     R      |
+----------+----------+------------+
```

I want to pick values based on the emp_status which will be passed dynamically

> ```
>  1. If emp_status='A' it should fetch emp_codes with emp_status='A'
>  2. If emp_status='I' it should fetch all emp_codes except emp_status='I'
>  3. If emp_status is null then fetch all emp_codes.
> ```

How to write single sql query with all the conditions?

Comment: what if emp_status ='R' or else ?

Comment: I will be passing emp_status either A or I or null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional `WHERE` clause using `OR` and `AND` operator as follows:

> ```
> SELECT EMP_CODE FROM YOUR_TABLE
> WHERE ('&INPUT_STATUS' = 'A' AND emp_status='A')
>    OR ('&INPUT_STATUS' = 'I' AND emp_status<>'I')
>    OR ('&INPUT_STATUS' IS NULL)
> ```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `case..when` expression like this :

```
SELECT *
  FROM tab
 WHERE CASE 
       WHEN :emp_status='A' THEN 'A'
       WHEN :emp_status='I' THEN emp_status 
       WHEN :emp_status is null THEN emp_status 
        END = emp_status
   AND ( emp_status != 'I' OR :emp_status is null )
```

where `:emp_status` is bind variable to be passed into the query.

Alternatively, you can also use `DECODE()` function

```
SELECT *
  FROM tab
 WHERE DECODE( :emp_status, 'A', 'A', 'I', emp_status, null , emp_status ) = emp_status
   AND ( emp_status != 'I' OR :emp_status is null )
```

Comment: Is condition #2 from question handled here?

Comment: No.still you are missing condition #2 from question. OP need `emp_status` except `I` when input is `I`